# How to return the email template with data as raw html in cakephp3.6?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi guys i have a code here for sending an email using template and i want to return the template as raw html. How can i achieve that?

```
$email = new Email();
    $email
        ->template('changelogrequest')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->subject($subject)
        ->to($to)
        ->from($this->from)
        ->viewVars($data);

    // get raw html here

    // Log::debug($email->getLayout());
    $email->send();
```

Comment: The `Email::send` function turns all that information into HTML somehow. Have you looked at what it does internally? One of the best things about PHP frameworks like Cake is that they're just PHP code, so you can dig right into them to see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: you're right, the send() method returns all html information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The send() method returns an array of the email informations including the raw html. Thanks to Greg Schmidt.

```
 $html = email->send();
 Log::debug($html)
```